# How do I change the UIKeyboard when using the UISearchBar?

Tags: iphone

I want to set the keyboard type of the UISearchBar to UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert, but I can't seem to access the UIKeyboard of the UISearchBar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to access the inner `UITextField` in the `UISearchBar` itself.

```
UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)[[searchBar subviews] objectAtIndex:0];
textField.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert;
```

Comment: Thank you!

The correct property is keyboardAppearance by the way.